# How to run unit tests by Maven Tycho Surfire with custom URL protocols (java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol)

Tags: junit, osgi, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin, url-protocol

I have experience some difficulties to run JUnit test that needs to use custom URL handler declared as `src/sun/net/www/protocol/exotic/Handler.java`

Tycho's surefire does some different execution of tests that result in failed tested. The exception is obvious: `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol`

I tried to figure out who is responsible for it. And I found out that if I create a simple Maven project with one test class and one custom handler than Maven surefire works fine since version 2.4. Before it was failing too. So I guess that Maven Tycho is using an old implementation.

Do you have any idea how to enable custom protocols in JUnit tests run by Maven Tycho?

Comment: Create bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413510

Comment: Unlike maven-surefire, tycho-surefire starts an OSGi runtime. Do the custom protocol handlers work in an OSGi runtime? Google seems to know a lot about this...